# Stackpanel IsMouseOver is False - when mouse is over the gap between stackPanel Items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following WPF control

[image]

And it looks like this when the app is running.

[image]

The problem is - that the popup - is Closed when my mouse is between the buttons. (the gap between the U, B & NB buttons)

As You can see - Popup.IsOpen property is bound to the stackPanel - IsMouseOver

How can I solve this ? So that the Popup would be open while my mouse is between the mentioned buttons ? (preferably without any code-behind)

Comment: does explicitly setting the value to True in the binding expression make a difference? ie: "{Binding ElemenentName=UBPanel, Path=IsMouseOver, Value="True", ....}"

Comment: I don't think You can write it that way. At least intelisense is not happy about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the StackPanel to Transparent (or whatever color works for you). For some reason, setting the Background brush (even to Transparent) allows the IsMouseOver to work as you would expect. Likely some WPF magic with layout and rendering optimization.

```
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel x:Name="ThePanel" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBox Margin="5">WOOT</TextBox>
            <TextBox Margin="5">WOOT</TextBox>
            <TextBox Margin="5">WOOT</TextBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ThePanel, Path=IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay}">
            <!--stuff-->
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: do you why this works whereas the stackpanel doesn't?  Doesn't seem overly intuitive to me...

Comment: @sous2817 WPF and intuition, a dangerous combo! Actually, your question made me test setting the stackpanel's background property. It works also! I never realized this because I ran into this issue with .xaml images and mouse over detection, and for those it made sense to put a border around it. I'll adjust my solution. Thanks!

Comment: outstanding, if I could upvote your answer twice, I would!  Now I just need to try and remember this issue for when it happens to me.

Comment: Great find! I had the same issue with DockPanel and this solution worked.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for the backgound for all panels is null, and when the background is null the touch and mouse events will not work. Set the stackpanel background to transparent or other color.